# how to disable FlatList auto inertia glide

Tags: react-native

When i drag and release finger , flatlist will glide automatically for a while.
I want disable the auto inertia glide,it means :
after release finger, flatlist stops scrolling at once.

How to do with flatlist?
Thanks!

Comment: try out this https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/scrollview#onmomentumscrollbegin

Answer (score 0):

Set the `decelerationRate` property to `{0}`.

For example:

```
<FlatList
   ...
   decelerationRate={0} 
   ...
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
<FlatList
   ...
   decelerationRate="fast" 
   ...
/>
```

Scrolling will degrade much faster than normal which kind of give the feeling of no momentum.